# Get Custom Exception from Integrated Step Function (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, state-machine, aws-serverless, aws-step-functions

I am calling a StepFunction (lets says util sf) inside another StepFunction (lets say main sf) using "startExecution.sync" in resource. The util sf Fail state has "Error": "MyCustomError" and "Cause": "MyCustomCause". So when this util sf fails I want to catch "MyCustomError" however I get can exception of type "States.TaskFailed". Is there a way to get "MyCustomError" instead, like in Lambda we do get "MyCustomError" when thrown from it, but it's not happening with StepFunction.

Comment: Could you invoke the util step function from within a lambda function step?